# How can i use linq to make a console application in C# for counting vowel in a sentence

Tags: c#, linq

I am trying make a program to count the number of vowels in a sentence but looks like it could be easily implemented with Linq. But have no idea about this.
Please help me or provide some link.

Thanks,

Comment: Do you need to count the "Y" in words with no {A,E,I,O,U}?

Comment: No. The occurence of all the vowels.

Answer (score 6):

That's definitely easy. You're just taking each letter in turn, and seeing if it's in one of another set. Fortunately, string implements `IEnumerable<char>`, so taking each character in turn is really natural with LINQ.

The `Enumerable.Count` method has an overload accepting a *predicate* - it returns the number of items in the sequence which match the predicate. Then you've just got to work out a predicate meaning "is this character a vowel". Using `string.Contains(char)` is the easiest way here.

This will do it:

```
int count = sentence.Count(c => "AEIOUaeiou".Contains(c));
```

Comment: Ah yes, that's valid in the US. What about the rest of us?
Whether a letter is a vowel is very dependent on where you're from :)
Here in Denmark 'Y' is a vowel and so is 'Æ', 'Ø', and 'Å'

Comment: FWIW: `int count = sentence.ToLower().Count(c => "aeiou".Contains(c));` But that's just me being picky :p

Comment: i am basic learner and didn't understand the meaning of all this. Can you please explain a little bit more with an example.

Comment: In English, y is a consonant in the word Yellow, but a vowel in the word Sky.

Comment: @Ashutosh: Which bit don't you understand?

Comment: @Jon I just hope that Ashutosh's teacher accepts your simple answer :D